# Property 'key' does not exist on type 'string | { key: string; element: Element; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

WHy is this error message

```
Property 'key' does not exist on type 'string | { key: string; element: Element; }'
```

when I input the following code

```
<th key={header?.key ? header.key : header} ref={ref}>
```

Header has the following type, so it should allow .key

```
export type Column<T = any> = {
  header: {key: string, element: JSX.Element} | string;
  size: keyof typeof COLUMN_SIZES;
  sortable?: boolean;
  property: string;
  ref?: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLTableHeaderCellElement>;
  render?: (datum: T, index?: number) => string;
  renderer?: React.FC<IRendererProps>;
};
```

Comment: solved with typeof ```header === "string" ? header : header.key```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string` doesn't have a `key` property, and `header` can be a `string`, so TypeScript doesn't allow you to access its `key` unconditionally. You need to add a check to narrow the type before accessing `key`.

One way to do that is to check whether it's actually a `string`:

```
typeof header == 'string' ? header : header?.key
```